# Tableview's content height is always zero

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with delegate and datasource set. I'm changing the height of table view dynamically. I also have a dropdown, When it is clicked once I'll show the table view if it's clicked again I'll hide it.
If I use tableview.isHidden = true/false it's hiding the table view but the blank space is visible. On debugging tableview.contentSize.height is always zero.
Can someone please guide me to the right direction. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Seems like a lot is going on. Could you please rephrase a bit and add some more information on what you are doing and how. What is your current result and what is your expected result. If possible even some code on "changing the height dynamically" and possibly other parts. A screenshot or a video may be very helpful as well. Setting (table) view "hidden" property should not effect the layout and "blank space" is expected unless you are using a stack view. If you are using a stack view then that is important information as well...

Comment: I'm just trying to achieve layout like showing mail recipients detail. I have tableView's height outlet , And I'll set it(tableHeight.constant) to zero/content size based on dropdown value(to show/hide). Current since the contentsize.height is always zero my tableview is hidden always.@MaticOblak

Comment: Please tag with UIKit APIs. I don't want to see any more UIKit ever again if I can help it!

Comment: It is possible that zero size does not even compute content size. There are also other reasons why you should avoid resizing table view. Try adding another view where your table view is and enable clipping subviews. Put the table view on this subview with left, right and bottom constraints. Now always keep table view of size of its content view. The new view should change size accordingly to your visibility flag. This should also give you a nice animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the .isHidden attribute hides it from being visible but doesn't automatically adjust the layout to account for the fact it isn't visible.

There are two approaches that have worked well for me.

**Stack View**

1. If you do want to show/hide an entire table view, I've found embedding the elements within a stack view can really help with layouts in this scenario.  Say you have title, button, tableview as three elements in the view controller.  You can put each in their own stack view, all within an overall stack view.  Then if you do

```swift
tableViewStackView.isHidden = true
```

Then the parent stack view adjusts layouts to account for the hidden item, resizing as you'd like.

**Table View Sections**

2. If instead you are showing / hiding sections or rows in a table, then you can use something like the below, where you toggle the .opened attribute as the user taps the header row?

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if item.opened == false {
       return 1 //only show the first row in the the section 
    }
       return items[section].rowCount + 1 //show all rows in the section
}
```

There are plenty of good tutorials out there for show/hide sections in a tableview that can hell with this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Steve!. I have tried using stackView , My tableview's Contentsize is always zero and hence cellForRowAt is not being called.How to make conntentSize non-zero..

Comment: Ah...in which case, there could be a lot going on.  Are you creating cells programatically or via storyboard?